# Xamarin forms convert png stream to svg string

Tags: svg, xamarin.forms, png

In my Xamarin Forms app I receive a signature from Xamarin.Controls.SignaturePad.Forms in a Stream and PNG format. I would like to store the signature as SVG in the database.

I looked around in Internet but not able to find a solution. Can anyone help me?

Many thanks!

Comment: you can't just convert a bitmap to a vector image.  You may be able to build a SVG using the Strokes data from the control

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Yes I can get the Strokes data from the control. But how do I use them to create the SVG string? Thanks

Comment: I don't know.  You would have to look at the Strokes data and figure out how they correspond to the instructions in an SVG.  I'd guess it's probably not that complicated, but I've never tried it

Comment: Many thanks, will follow your suggestion